# Как убрать пробелы рядом со знаком +

Tags: python, строки

```py
a = 'qwert y + qwerty'
```

Когда я делаю `replace()` то он мне выдает так:

```py
>>> print(a.replace(' ','').split('+'))
['qwerty', 'qwerty']
```

А когда я делаю просто `split()`, он мне выдает:

```py
['qwert y ', ' qwerty']
```

Но мне надо чтобы он выдавал так:

```py
['qwert y', 'qwerty']
```

Чтобы пробелы он убирал только рядом с + а в остальных местах чтоб он не трогал.

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
print(a.replace(' ','').split('+'))
```

На

```
print([x.strip() for x in a.split('+')])
```

Comment: если я так сделаю то он выведет ```['qwert y ', ' qwerty']``` с пробелом в начале и в конце мне этого не надо

Comment: @QadyrIsrafilov поправил

Answer (score 1):

Сплитьте по пробелам вокруг знака +.

```
a.split(" + ")
```

Comment: А вдруг пробелы то есть, то нет. Хотя если они точно есть всегда, то ваше решение будет работать.

Comment: Ну да, я согласен с вашим замечанием. Просто по вопросу не понятно какие конкретно у нас могут быть входные данные

Comment: А это типичная история на этом сайте - всегда приходится гадать и додумывать за автора вопроса, какие у него могут быть варианты данных. Полной картины обычно никто не даёт, даже если настойчиво просить об этом в комментариях. )

Answer (score 1):

В этом случае надёжнее воспользоваться **регулярными выражениями**, указав, что вокруг знака `+` может быть произвольное количество пробелов. А может и не быть, это сработает одинаково хорошо в обоих случаях:

```
import re

a = 'qwert y + qwerty'
b = re.split(r'\s*\+\s*', a)
print(b)
```

Вывод:

```
['qwert y', 'qwerty']
```

Расшифровка регулярного выражения `\s*\+\s*`:

- `\s*` - произвольное число пробелов количеством от нуля или больше
- `\+` - знак `+`, его нужно экранировать бэкслэшем
- `\s*` - произвольное число пробелов количеством от нуля или больше